# Removing null values from lead function

Tags: postgresql

I have used the following postgresql query to find the maximum difference between timestamp events for each user:

```
select 
   sq.user_id, 
   max(sq.diffs) inactivity 
from (
    select 
       user_id,
       (lead("when", 1, now()) over (partition by user_id order by "when") - "when") as diffs
    from tracking_viewed
 ) as sq 
 group by sq.user_id 
 order by inactivity desc;
```

This query works for a different table, but it returns all null values for the "when" column that includes nulls.

How can I remove or skip nulls from the lead and partition functions?

Comment: Do you mean that there are NULL values in `"when"`, but you don't want NULL values in the query result?

Comment: Jack, can you put some sample data for better understanding of your problem?